# How to detect when RecyclerView with SnapHelper scrolled to the next item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have have a RecyclerView with SnapHelper to use RecyclerView like ViewPager for browse items one by one (like PagerView).

How to detect when user swiped to the next RecyclerView item?

I have tried addOnScrollListener using onScrollStateChanged and onScrolled but they called many times when user scroll from item to next item.

Any idea how i can detect when user swiped to the next RecyclerView item please.

Thanks

SnapHelper Class:

```
public class SnapHelperOneByOne extends LinearSnapHelper {
@Override
public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager 
layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY) {

    if (!(layoutManager instanceof RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider)) {
        return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    }
    final View currentView = findSnapView(layoutManager);
    if (currentView == null) {
        return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    }
    LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) 
 layoutManager;
    int position1 = myLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    int position2 = myLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    int currentPosition = layoutManager.getPosition(currentView);
    if (velocityX > 400) {
        currentPosition = position2;
    } else if (velocityX < 400) {
        currentPosition = position1;
    }
    if (currentPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    }
    return currentPosition;
}
}
```